# Generate numpy matrix with unique range for each element

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to generate random matrices. However, each element of the random matrix has a different range. So I want to generate a random matrix such that each element has that random number within that range. So far i've been able to generate matrices with unique column ranges:

```
c1 = np.random.uniform(low=2, high=1000, size=(15,1))
c2 = np.random.uniform(low=0.001, high=100, size=(15,1))
c3 = np.random.uniform(low=30, high=10000, size=(15,1))
c4 = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=25, size=(15,1))

mtx = np.concatenate((c1,c2,c3,c4), axis=1)
```

Now Low and high for rows in mtx is also quite different. How can I generate such random matrix with each row element also having unique range and not just columns?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by each row element also having unique range?

Comment: Do you mean that each element in the matix should fall within the range of of two different uniform distibutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do to achieve what you want is the following:

1. Specify the `low` and `high` for each column and each row
2. Check for each element what the range is that it can be sampled from (that means the highest `low` and the lowest `high` of the two ranges imposed by its row and is column)
3. Sample each element separately (from a uniform distribution) with the element's specified high and low.

Now each element in each row will certainly be within the row's limits and the same would go for elements in a column.

You should be careful though not to select mutual exclusive ranges in rows and columns.

That said here some code that does this (with comments):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
n_rows = 15
n_cols = 4

# here I make random highs and lows for each row and column
# these are lists of tuples like this: [(39, 620), (83, 123), (67, 243), (77, 901)]
# where each tuple contains the low and high for the column (or row). 
ranges_rows = [ (randint(0,100), randint(101, 1001)) for _ in range(n_rows) ]
ranges_cols = [ (randint(0,100), randint(101, 1001)) for _ in range(n_cols) ]

# make an empty matrix
mtx = np.empty((n_rows, n_cols))

# fill in the matrix
for x in range(n_rows): 
    for y in range(n_cols):
        # get the specified low and high for both the column and row of the element
        row_low, row_high = ranges_rows[x]
        col_low, col_high = ranges_cols[y]
        
        # the low and high for each element should be within range of both the
        # row and column restrictions
        elem_low  = max([row_low, col_low])
        elem_high = min([row_high, col_high])
        
        # get the element within the range
        rand_elem = np.random.uniform(low=elem_low, high=elem_high)
        # put it in its right place in the matrix
        mtx[x,y] = rand_elem
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would probably work:

```
low  = np.array([   2, 0.001,    30,  1])
high = np.array([1000,   100, 10000, 25])
l = 15

mtx = np.random.rand((l,) + low.shape) * (high - low)[None, :] + low[None, :]
```